# Signature of sorted method in SeqLike

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I don't understand the purpose for the signature of the `sorted` method within the `SeqLike` trait:

```
def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Repr
```

More precise, I don't get:

1. The reason for `B>:A`
2. What does `Repr` mean?

Perhaps you can shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance for the effort in answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The method takes an implicit `Ordering` which should be able to handle some *supertype* of `A` (hence `B >: A`). I.e. you should be able to use an `Ordering[AnyVal]` to compare `Int` values (as `AnyVal` is a supertype of `Int`).
2. `Repr` is a type parameter of the `SeqLike` trait itself (`SeqLike[+A, +Repr]`) described as "the type of the actual collection containing the elements". This is meant to ensure that methods like `sorted` will return a collection of the same type (e.g. `List.sorted` will still be a `List`).

Comment: I still don't understand the need for 1. Can you give an example of why I should be able to use an Ordering[AnyVal] to compare Int and not only a plain Ordering[Int]. So, I undersand the WHAT, I don't understand the WHY.

Comment: If you have an Ordering[Animal], you should be able to sort a List[Dog].

Comment: what @JoePallas said :)

Comment: @JoePallas Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`[B >: A]` means that `sorted` can be called with any ordering on B, where B is a supertype of A.

I suppose A is the type parameter of the trait itself, i.e.

SeqLike is defined as `SeqLike[A, This]`. To be exhaustive, as `SeqLike[A, +This <: SeqLike[A, This] with Seq[A]]`. The `This <: SeqLike[A, This]` is F-bounded polymorphism.

```
trait A[T <: A[T]] {} // the type parameter to A must be an A
class C extends A[C] {} // this is how you use it.
```

The [actual return type of `SeqLike.sorted`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SeqLike) is `This`.

This is useful, because this allows SeqLike's methods to not only return `SeqLike`s, but also subtypes!

Going back to the simple exemple earlier...

```
trait Model[T <: Model[T]] {
  def find(id: Int): T = ...
}
class User extends Model[User]
val model: User = new User().find(3) # no need to cast.
```

Comment: Your answer is momentarily too complicated for my level of understanding. I will get back to it when my Scala comprehension evolve. Please see my comment for Costi to understand my initial question in more detail. Thanks!! I upvoted you but the points are not yet visible because of my limited history and reputation on SO.

Comment: No problem :-). Hopefully it'll help someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple explanation why `B >: A`:

Let's consider this class (doesn't compile):

```
class C[+T] {
  def m(x: T): T = x
}
```

`+T` means covariant, i.e. `C[Any]` is a superclass of e.g. `C[Int]`. Now (`"123"` is a `String`, so it's also `Any`):

```
val cInt: C[Any] = new C[Int]
cInt.m("123") // ??? We are supposed to return Int here
```

In reality:

```
class C[+T] {
  def m[A >: T](x: A): A = x
}
```

so (compiler infers `A` as the nearest common ancestor of `Any` and `String` here, which is `Any`)

```
val cInt: C[Any] = new C[Int]
cInt.m("123") // Any = 123
```

Definition of `SeqLike`: `trait SeqLike[+A, +Repr]`, note `+A`